# Django: how to render form field without double quotes

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-forms

Here is what I'm trying to achieve. I want to replace 3 static html inputs (checkboxes) with django form fields (forms.Form). When I render this piece of django template:

```
<button id="visitas-mes-opcoes" class="btn btn-default col-xs-12" type="button" data-toggle="popover" 
  title="<label class='text-info'>Opções</label>"
  data-content="
   <div id='opcoes-checkbox' class='checkbox'>
     <label>
       {{ form_pesquisar_visitas.maquinas_usadas }}
       <input id='maquinas-usadas' class='checkbox-option' name='maquinas-usadas' type='checkbox' value='1'>
       Máquinas Usadas
     </label>
     <hr style='margin: 8px -10px 8px -30px; width: 180px;'/>
     <label>
       <input id='vendas-efetuadas' class='checkbox-option' name='vendas-efetuadas' type='checkbox' value='1'>
       Vendas Efetuadas
     </label>
     <hr style='margin: 8px -10px 8px -30px; width: 180px;'/>
     <label>
       <input id='vendas-perdidas' class='checkbox-option' name='vendas-perdidas' type='checkbox' value='1'>
       Vendas Perdidas
     </label>
   </div>">
   <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-collapse-down"></span>
</button>
```

I get the following result:

[image]

But I was expecting something as the original html:

[image]

Seems to me django is introducing some double quotes during the field rendering. Anyone knows how to work around this? I'm open to any suggestions.

PS: I inherited this html from a legacy PHP code that I'm trying to convert to python Django for new features and easier maintanance :/

Comment: Injecting markup as string within a tag's attribute is a terrible idea to start with (I'm not even sure this is valid HTML actually, but even then...).  You could of course apply a custom filter to escape quotes but not having markup as a tag's attribute value would be a safer solution IMHO.

Comment: I agree with you. But like I said: I inherited this "excelent piece of code" hehehe. Can a filter be used to override the field render method?

Comment: A filter will not "override the field render method", but it can process the string returned by the field's rendering. Also note that you can do most of the rendering manually cf https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/article/2017/08/19/how-to-render-django-form-manually.html#expanding-the-form-fields